# Timing Fade in Order UsingJquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

What I'm trying to do is the following:

1. When the user clicks a trigger, an overlay comes on the screen *(this is working)*
2. after the overlay fades in, I want to be able to control the delay time before the list items of a UL fade in
3. Once the list items complete their fade in, I want to trigger two other elements to fade in on the page

Right now I've just got it to the point where the `list-items` fadeIn, but I don't know how to control the time prior to their fade in.

Can anyone help?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var square = $('.square');
  var ocn = $('.off-canvas-nav');
  var flag = false;

  square.click(function() {
    ocn.addClass('showOCN');
    flag = true;
    $(".mainNav li").each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay(300 * i).fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.page {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.square {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.off-canvas-nav {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.showOCN {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.mainNav {
  list-style-type: none;
  left: 20%;
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.mainNav>li {
  margin: 30px 0px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="off-canvas-nav">
    <ul class="mainNav">
      <li class=".fadeMe">Items</li>
      <li class=".fadeMe">Items</li>
      <li class=".fadeMe">Items</li>
      <li class=".fadeMe">Items</li>
      <li class=".fadeMe">Items</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you changed part of the question at some point and did not answer all of the parts. Check last edit ;) cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `setTimeout()` to trigger the fadeIn :

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $(".mainNav li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(300 * i).fadeIn(1000);
  });
}, 2000); //After 2 seconds
```

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var square = $('.square');
  var ocn = $('.off-canvas-nav');
  var flag = false;

  square.click(function() {
    ocn.addClass('showOCN');
    flag = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".mainNav li").each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(300 * i).fadeIn(1000);
      });
    }, 2000); //After 2 seconds
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.page {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.square {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.off-canvas-nav {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.showOCN {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.mainNav {
  list-style-type: none;
  left: 20%;
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.mainNav>li {
  margin: 30px 0px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="off-canvas-nav">
    <ul class="mainNav">
      <li class=".fadeMe">Items</li>
      <li class=".fadeMe">Items</li>
      <li class=".fadeMe">Items</li>
      <li class=".fadeMe">Items</li>
      <li class=".fadeMe">Items</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much! Can I ask a follow-up question?

Comment: So I'm going to add a close button that toggles off the screen, and make it so if the user click anything that is not a link, the off canvas nav goes away, will the animation replay once the trigger is clicked again?

Comment: Not  sure which link you mean bro, but try to update the fiddle with the changes you describe or if necessary post a new question..

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `jQuery` [`.promise()`](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) and [`when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

> .**promise(** [type ] [, target ] **)**
>
> **Description**: *Return a Promise object to observe when all actions of a
>   certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have finished.*

**Edit** Added a second promise to display a chain of events, try it in the code snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var square = $('.square');
  var ocn = $('.off-canvas-nav');
  var flag = false;
  var sleeptime = 3000; 
  function effect(obj,ms) {
  console.log("Sleep for ... "+ms/1000+" seconds!");
  // other javascript code ....
  return obj.delay(ms).addClass("sleepy");
  }
  square.click(function() {
    ocn.addClass('showOCN');
    square.removeClass("red blue");
    flag = true;
    console.clear();
    console.log( "Started..." );
    $.when( effect($(this),sleeptime) ).done(function() {  
    console.log("Waking up!\nAnimation start");
    $(".mainNav li").each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay(300 * i).fadeIn(1000);
    }).promise().done(function() {
    // put the rest of your javascript code here
    // e.g.
    ocn.removeClass('showOCN');
    $(this).hide();
    square.delay(2000).addClass("red").promise().done(function() { 
    square.delay(2000).addClass("blue");
    console.log( "Turned color blue!\nSecond Promise Finished!" );
    flag = false;
    });
    console.log( "Animation ended.\nFirst Promise Finished\n Turned color red!" );
  });
  });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.page {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.square {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.red {
  background-color: #f00;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #00f;
}
.off-canvas-nav {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .8s ease;
}

.showOCN {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.mainNav {
  list-style-type: none;
  left: 20%;
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.mainNav>li {
  margin: 30px 0px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="off-canvas-nav">
    <ul class="mainNav">
      <li class=".fadeMe">Items</li>
      <li class=".fadeMe">Items</li>
      <li class=".fadeMe">Items</li>
      <li class=".fadeMe">Items</li>
      <li class=".fadeMe">Items</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```